# Django: autonumbering in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

Im currently trying to figure out how to autonumber my tables in my html template.
I can't seem to use the id in the database as it is not autoincrementing as it it is user dependant what they see, so the user would see not a correct ordering. Instead of seeing the table numbering go `1. 2. 3.`  it is `4. 8. 9.` for example.

Originally i have tried this, which gave me the wrong outcome as described above:

**template.html**

```
        {% for item in x%}   
            <tr>                    
                <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.a}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.b}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.c}}</td>
            </tr>
```

I have tried something with a while loop:

**template.html**

```
        {% for item in x %}
            {% while z<= item %}
                {% z=z+1 %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ z }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.a}}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.b}}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.c }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endwhile %}
        {% endfor %}
```

For your reference the model that these templates refer to:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class x(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forloop.counter` to count the iterations of a loop. Try this:

```
{% for item in x %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.a}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.b}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.c}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Reference: [for template tag - Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: Oh wow thank you, is it that simple? I have read about that `forloop.counter` but probably misunderstood it. It took way to much time to figure that out, hahaha. Thank you very much!